# PyCharm IDE unreachable code when using try finally within a while loop

Tags: python, pycharm

The following code causes **PyCharm** to detect the last line as 'unreachable code', despite it being completely reachable.

```
import random

def test_func():
    while True:
        print("start")
        try:
            if random.random() > 0.5:
                break
        finally:
            print("Finally")
    print("Done")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_func()
```

When the try/finally block is not included, the error does not occur.

Here's a relevant screenshot:

[image: PyCharm showing print("Done") as unreachable]

Comment: is it an error or warning?

Comment: Looks like Pycharm is just wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was already reported [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-19739) and [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-1177) and it should be fixed in PyCharm 2016.3.

Comment: Darnit. Ninja'd me!

Comment: Thank you! I should note I did only have it with try/finally, not with try/catch, but it seems to be the same issue.

Comment: @DaboRoss interestingly enough, I'm running 2016.3.2 and 2017 EAP - in both cases issue is still reproducible. I guess we should wait for the next patch release..

Comment: @alecxe since it is slightly different from the reported issues, being about try/finally (while working correctly without try/finally), do you think I should report it as a separate issue?

Comment: @DaboRoss I guess you should comment on the existing one (the second one). Looks like this use case breaks the fix.

Comment: I've added a comment to the second linked issue.